# How exactly do I "show" that $ z = ae^{i\alpha} + be^{-i\alpha} $ represents an ellipse?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conic-sections

Here is an equation and I want to know how I can show that this represents an ellipse ($a$ and $b$ are complex constants and $\alpha$ is a real variable):
$$ 
z = ae^{i\alpha} + be^{-i\alpha} 
$$

I wanna learn how a mathematician would approach a problem like this, like where would you start for example. I have no idea where to even begin with problems like these.

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yes I do

Comment: What definition do you have for an ellipse?

Comment: @Peter The definition that I have for an ellipse is that it has two focal points and the sum of the distances to any two points on the ellipse from the focal points is constant

Comment: It is very likely that you need to show that set $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbf{R}^2\mid x+iy=ae^{it}+be^{-it}, t\in\mathbf{R} \}$$ is the same as $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbf{R}^2\mid \frac{x^2}{p^2}+\frac{y^2}{q^2}=1\}$$ for some real number $p$ and $q$. In general, when one says that "an equation represent some mathematical object $X$", one means the solution set to the equation has the defining property of $X$.

Comment: @user1046533 Again I don't know how to get my foot in the door for problems like that. Am I just not mathematically mature enough

Comment: Separate the real and imaginary parts to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand complex mappings, it is often usefull to either split an equation into real and imaginary part, or to transform it entirely into polar coordiantes. Let's try the second idea:

Write $a = R_1 e^{i\phi_1}$, $b=R_2e^{-i\phi_2}$, then you get:

$$z(\alpha) = ae^{i\alpha}+be^{-i\alpha} = R_1e^{i(\phi_1+\alpha)}+R_2e^{-i(\phi_2+\alpha)}$$

To further simplify this, we want both terms to have the same argument. Notice that the image $\{z(\alpha) : \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$ traced out by $z(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ does not change if we reparametrize the curve, i.e. we can introduce a new parametrization $\beta$ via $\alpha = \beta - \underbrace{\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2}}_{=:\phi}$, which transforms above formula to the following:

$$z(\beta ) = R_1 e^{i(\beta+\frac{\phi_1}{2}-\frac{\phi_2}{2})} + R_2e^{-i(\beta -\frac{\phi_1}{2}+\frac{\phi_2}{2})} = R_1e^{i(\beta+\phi)}+R_2e^{-i(\beta-\phi)} = e^{i\phi}(R_1e^{i\beta}+R_2e^{-i\beta}),$$
where $\phi = \frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2}$ is just some constant, meaning $e^{i\phi}$ is a rotation by the angle $\phi$.

Now you can use Euler's identity $e^{i\beta} = \cos\beta + i\sin\beta$ to further simplify this, using that $\cos\beta = \cos(-\beta)$ and $-\sin\beta =\sin(-\beta)$. In the end, this should yield

$$z(\beta) = e^{i\phi}((R_1+R_2)\cos\beta + i(R_1-R_2)\sin\beta),$$

Basically (for $R_1 \neq\pm R_2$) the term $(R_1+R_2)\cos\beta + i(R_1-R_2)\sin\beta)$ just describes an standard ellipse centerd at $0$ with radii $R_1+R_2$ and $R_1-R_2$ (since it satisfies an equation of the form $\frac{x^2}{\lambda}+\frac{y^2}{\delta}=1$ for $\lambda,\delta>0$), while the factor $e^{i\phi}$ in front of it rotates this ellipse around the origin by $\phi$.

If you prefer cartesian coordinates: $$z(\beta) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}(R_1+R_2)\cos\beta \\ (R_1-R_2)\sin\beta\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: How did you find that it satisfies an equation of that form

Comment: I'm not sure how to use code in the comments sorry im a noob

Comment: No problem. I may have been a bit sloppy with notation: In this case I meant $x = \Re z(\beta)$ and $y=\Im z(\beta)$, so for the equation to work you basically just use that for $R_1 + R_2 \neq 0$ and $R_1-R_2\neq0$, you can normalize the final equation for $z(\beta)$: $$\frac{(\Re z(\beta))^2}{(R_1+R_2)^2} + \frac{(\Im z(\beta))^2}{(R_1-R_2)^2} = \cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta = 1$$
Here we of course have to assume $\lambda = (R_1+R_2)^2,\delta =(R_1-R_2)^2$ to be both non-zero. Elsewise we don't get an ellipse at all, just some degenerated conic section.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you mind sharing what textbooks you have used in the past or recently that may have helped with a question like this?

Comment: Like what gave you the idea to write a = ... b = .... etc.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If you're satisfied with the answer, you can mark it as "accepted" btw. About your further questions: I think when dealing with geometric problems, one should always think about which coordinates are most appropriate to describe the problem at hand. The thing about complex numbers is that there are a lot of ways to view them: You can view $z = a+bi\in\mathbb{C}$ just as a vector $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, but written in polar coordinates as $z = Re^{i\varphi} = R(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)$ you get a beautiful connection to circles or just periodic functions in general.

Comment: You can also think of $z=a+bi$ as a rotation/rescaling-matrix $z\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$: Set $1 := \left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$, $i :=  \left(\begin{matrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and thus: $$z = a+bi =  \left(\begin{matrix}a & -b \\ b& a\end{matrix}\right)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\phi &-\sin\phi\\ -\sin\phi & \cos\phi \end{matrix}\right) \text{ for some }\phi\in\mathbb{R}$$ In this setting, complex multiplication just follows from the rules of matrix multiplication (you can e.g. see directly that $i^2=-1$), and also $\det z = a^2+b^2 =: |z|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna learn how a mathematician would approach a problem like this

I will try to answer this part of the question. There are various ways a geometric object is defined. **Showing that something represents a given geometric object $G$ means matching any of its definitions**

Take the example of a circle of center $C$ and radius $R$. It is usually defined as the set of all points in the plane whose distance to $C$ is equal to $R$. Then, using a coordinates system, we can obtain an equation of the circle: if $C(a,b)$, then a point $M(x,y)$ is on the circle if and only if

$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$$

Let's call this the *standard equation* of the circle. Note that we could also have used it as a definition since it is equivalent to the original definition. To show that something represents a circle, you can either show it is the set of points equidistant to a fixed point, or show that you can rewrite the data you have into the standard equation of a circle. The exact strategy depends on the problem.

Now, there is not a single method to show that something represents a geometric object. Here are a few examples:

1. to show that the equation $x^2-2x+y^2+2y-2=0$ represents a circle, you can *complete the square*:

$$x^2-2x+y^2+2y-2=0 \iff (x-1)^2-1+(y+1)^2-1-2=0 \iff (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=2^2$$

so the equation represents a circle of center $(1,-1)$ and radius $2$ (by comparison with the standard form).

2. The set of all points $(x,y)$ such that $x=2\cos(t)$ and $y=1+2\sin(t)$, $t\in\mathbb R$, is a circle, since $x^2+(y-1)^2=4\cos^2(t)+4\sin^2(t)=4$.
3. You can use a [rotation of coordinate axes](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rotation_of_axes) to show that $3x^2-2\sqrt{3}xy+y^2+8x+8\sqrt{3}y=0$ is a hyperbola by changing the equation into the standard equation of a hyperbola
4. If $a=2+3i$, the equation $\overline{z}+\overline{a}z=1$ represents a line. Indeed, write $z=x+iy$ with $x,y$ real numbers. Then the equation is equivalent to

$$
(2+3i)(x-iy)+(2-3i)(x+iy)=1 
\iff
4x+6y=1
$$

which is a standard equation for a line.

Answer (score 0):

$z=ae^{it}+be^{-it}, a,b,t\in \Re \implies x+iy=(a+b) \cos t+i(a-b)\sin t$

$\implies x=(a+b) \cos t, y=(a-b)\sin t \implies \cos t=\frac{x}{a+b}, \sin t=\frac{y}{a-b}$

Squaring and adding las two we get $\frac{x^2}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(a-b)^2}=1,$
which is and ellipse if $a\ne b$.

If $b=a$ then $x+iy=2a \cos t,y=0$, it represents a line sefment on $x$axis from $x=-2a,$ to $x=2a$.